# Adding a password to an RDLC PDF or Excel in C# (ASP MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, rdlc

I have been using RDLCs for a short time to do basic reporting by binding my standard C# models (POCOs) to datasets and pushing them out to the report to represent data. So in my MVC Controller provided an action result that allowed the user to download the PDF upon a successful call to the RESTFUL API and then binding the data to the report.

```
public FileContentResult GenerateCensusReport(PersonReportModel model)
{
    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streams;
    string mimeType;
    byte[] renderedBytes;
    string encoding;
    string fileNameExtension;
    var resultModel = new PersonReportModel();
    var inputModel = new List<PersonReportModel>();
    var localReport = new LocalReport { ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/statsReportTemplate.rdlc") };

    //call api
    var tokenString = HttpContext.Items["tokenValue"];
    ServiceClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
        tokenString.ToString());

    DataObject.Data = model;
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataObject.Data);
    var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.Default, "application/json");
    var response = ServiceClient.PostAsync(ServiceUrl + "Report/ReportStats", content).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseResult = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JsonResponseObject>().Result;
        resultModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonReportModel>(responseResult.Data.ToString());
        inputModel.Add(resultModel);
    }

    var reportDataSourceOne = new ReportDataSource
    {
        Name = "DataSetPersonalStats",
        Value = inputModel
    };

    localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSourceOne);

    localReport.Refresh();

    var deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" + "<OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" + "</DeviceInfo>";

    renderedBytes = localReport.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension,
        out streams, out warnings);

    var fileName = "Census_Report_" + DateTime.Now + "_.pdf";

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

    return new FileContentResult(renderedBytes, mimeType);
}
```

However based on client request i have been requested to set a password on the document (or encrypt the document output) that will restrict access to data present in the document.In short when a client opens the PDF it should have a window prompting them for a password to access the information

I've searched everywhere for possible solutions and have come across several that suggested the use of iText Sharp and other third party tools that tend to have certain licencing restrictions.

Is there perhaps something that I could be missing in order to secure the PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a fix for such an issue using PDFSharp :)